# how to save ajax result as pdf file?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Trying to download a file which is dynamically generated by the the data posted. I have the results coming back. I'm just not sure how I can save the results into a proper file locally once the information (stream) is returned from the server.

Here is the ajax call:

```
function download_pdf(){
      alert("made it" + result_array); 
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "report_generation/downlaod_pdf.php",
                data: { result_array: result_array },

                success: function(results){
                    alert(results);
                },
                error: 
                    function(xmlHttpRequest, status, error){
                        alert(xmlHttpRequest + "| ajax failure: could not download haq report | " + status + " | error:" + error);
                        var xmlHttpRequestStr = "";
                        for(var x in xmlHttpRequest)
                            xmlHttpRequestStr = xmlHttpRequestStr + xmlHttpRequest[x];
                        alert(xmlHttpRequestStr);
                }
           });
}
```

This function is called from a hyperlink like so, and the success method is returning...

```
<a class="haq_button" href="javascript:download_pdf()"><span>Download Report As PDF</span></a>
```

UPDATE: Here is a snippet of code from the file generation in download_pdf

```
// set the headers, prevent caching
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: -1");
            header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

            // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
            if ($is_attachment) {
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$output_file_name\"");
            }
            else {
                    header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            }

            // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
            $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
            $content_types = array(
                    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
                    "zip" => "application/zip",
                    "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                    "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                    "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
            );
            $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
            header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

            //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
            {
                list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
                if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
                {
                    //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                    //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                    list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    $range = '';
                    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                    exit;
                }
}
    else
    {
        $range = '';
}

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

    //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
    if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
        header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
    }
    else
      header("Content-Length: $file_size");

    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    set_time_limit(0);
    fseek($file, $seek_start);

    while(!feof($file)) 
    {
        print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) 
        {
            @fclose($file);
            exit;
        }           
    }

    // file save was a success
    @fclose($file);
    exit;
```

Comment: If you know the name of the PDF file your PHP script is going to download then you can redirect to that URL using `top.location.href` and the browser will either open the PDF file if it has a PDF reading built in (like Chrome), or download the file if not. Or you can redirect to *another* PHP script that forces the user’s browser to send the file as a download.

Comment: @Martin Bean - Sorry this is my first time doing this. Should I be using <form> instead of Ajax?

Comment: I dont know how are you generating the pdf file...but how about this, you create the pdf and save it to a temp folder, then the ajax call return the link to the pdf file(download link)...i think that could be a more elegant approach

Comment: We discussed that but decided we just wanted to dynamcially create the pdf upon user's request. We even tested out the method you mentioned for testing. The download_pdf.php generates and returns the pdf it contains all the header info. just reviewing the contents of it now. Updating the post to include the missing info. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not posible. Only you can do is to open new browser window with that PDF url or change location of current window like that: window.location = 'report_generation/downlaod_pdf.php';

Comment: so remove the ajax call and call window.location = 'report_generation/downlaod_pdf.php';

How can I post the data?

Comment: How big size of data you want to post? If not so big you can send it by GET param: window.location = 'report_generation/downlaod_pdf.php? result_array[key]=val'
Otherwise you should use solution described below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19684001/2857469)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using javascript/ajax. You have to use regural download link, or in your case form. If you want to have some error handling using javascript if pdf generation fails and still keep the same page open, you can submit into a hidden iframe.

Comment: But my alert displays upon a success. So the pdf-generation is returning - why is this last step of saving the data locally impossible? This javascript is called from a regular download link. I will edit my post to include the link.

Comment: @user2672744 You have the content of the pdf file your javascript variable, but after this you have nowhere to move - you can't create a file from javascript, you can't trigger download with the bytes you have in javascript.

Comment: Ok. Can I use the AJAX call and allow the download.php file handle the request? I am looking into the PHP file now. Thanks

Comment: @user2672744 Do you mean if you can generate a temporary pdf on the server (this triggered by ajax), and then let the user download it? This would work, though I don't know why you want to complicate it.

Comment: okay i have the hyper link detailed above and i can have it redirect to report_generator/download_pdf.php but how do I post the data? it is not available anywhere in the form. I passed it in as a javascript variable.

Comment: @user2672744 You can create a hidden form, set the fields, and post it. All with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic form and submit it, it will open a new window/tab and if it fails you can show a message in that page. In anyway, the right way to handle and track an exception is not on the receiver, but sender (download_pdf.php)

To create a dynamic form:

```
var VerifyForm = document.createElement("form");
VerifyForm.target = "_blank"; //You must specify here your target
VerifyForm.method = "POST";
VerifyForm.action = "download_pdf.php";
var dataInput = document.createElement("input");
dataInput.type = "hidden";
dataInput.name = "mydata"; //var name
dataInput.value = value; //var value
VerifyForm.appendChild(dataInput); //Apend var to form, repeat for n
document.body.appendChild(VerifyForm);
VerifyForm.submit();
```

If you still try to it at your own way, is impossible, I recommend you read more about what means the capital "A" in "Ajax"

Comment: Well the files are only tiny... no more than 250kB in size, I actually believe they are closer to 150 kB

Comment: I posted code with the pdf generator... am I able to still make the connection via ajax and it will proceed with the download while not changing the window?

Comment: No, it's not about the size, is about you can't save to a file a response from ajax. Javascript do NOT manage files, and you still need a head of the file to be recognized. Search for questions on "how download with ajax".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the download of the file by adding these HTTP headers in the `downlaod_pdf.php`

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$your_file_name");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($your_file_content);
```

EDIT : and also add `window.location.href = your_php_script_path` in the js file